# How to fetch a dynamic data(if available) from search page and save it to a csv with respect to the searched result

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver

Am stuck with a scenario..

I have a condition like this..

For example, let us consider the google or linkedIn search.. Say results fetched be 10 per page. Lets assume in Each result few data like Title link(the first line), the page link(the second line) will be present for all profile.  third and fourth line will be of some description and that is present only for few profiles. I want to automate and save the data available for each result. ie. title link, page links, description(if available) and append it to a CSV file

## expected to look like below format.

Name | Location | URL | Description

X1 | X2 | X3 | Y4(If present)

Y1 | Y2 | Y3 | EMPTY(If absent)

Below is the code:

```
 while True:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 150)
        profile_loc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".demographic>dd>bdi")))
        profile_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".title.main-headline")))
        profile_all = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,".//*[contains(@class,'mod result idx')]")))

        profile_current = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@class='label' and text()='Current']//following::dd[1]/p[1]")))


        for each_link in profile_links:
            page_links = each_link.get_attribute('href')
            print(page_links)

        for each_name in profile_name:
            page_name = each_name.text
            print(page_name)

        for each_loc in profile_loc:
            page_loc = each_loc.text
            print(page_loc)

        for each_current in profile_current:
            page_current = str(each_current.text.encode("utf-8"))
            print(page_current)

            appendFile = open("E:\Balaji\Profile-Links.csv", 'a')
            appendFile.write(str(page_name + "|" + page_loc + "|" + page_links + "|" + page_current + "\n"))
            appendFile.close()
```

I did and it worked for links and other data which are present for all the search results(that is 10) and appended it. But my problem is am not able to append the description part(which is dynamically present / absent) to its respective links or profiles.

I identified the description(if present) and saved it to a variable, say(profile current. I tried it with some ridiculous code like below but it gets appended arbitrarily.

## Check whether description exists or not and save the result to page_current

```
 for each_current in profile_current:
if profile_current != "":
    page_current = str(each_current.text.encode("utf-8"))
else:
    page_current = "Empty"
print page_current
```

## Append the results in the csv file

```
  appendFile = open("E:\Balaji\Profile-Links.csv", 'a')
            appendFile.write(str(page_name + "|" + page_loc + "|" + page_links + "|" + page_current + "\n"))
            appendFile.close()
```

Kindly help me with this issue.